# Were only half of US college graduates from 2006-2011 employed full-time in 2012?

Tags: united-states, economics, work

According to an online article SmartMoney magazine titled, "[The Jobless Class of 2012](https://blogs.smartmoney.com/advice/2012/07/06/the-jobless-class-of-2012/)":

> Only a half of those who graduated since 2006 are now employed full
>   time, according to a recent Rutgers University survey.

Here's a [link to the PDF report that statement is based on](https://www.heldrich.rutgers.edu/sites/default/files/content/Chasing_American_Dream_Report.pdf), and the [news release covering it](https://news.rutgers.edu/medrel/news-releases/2012/05/chasing-the-american-20120510/) too. The report was the result of interviews with 444 graduates of four-year colleges and universities from the classes of 2006 through 2011.

Is it roughly true that half of those who graduated from colleges and universities from 2006 to 2011 were employed full time in 2012?

**UPDATE:** [According to analysis of a January 2011 U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics employment report](https://theautomaticearth.blogspot.com/2011/01/january-23-2011-only-47-of-working-age.html), "only 47% of working age Americans have full time jobs".

**UPDATE 2:**

> The number of young adults in America who have full-time employment is
>   currently at its lowest in four years, even for those workers who have
>   a college degree, according to a recent Gallup survey.
>
> Less than half, about 44 percent, of adults aged 18 to 29 held a
>   full-time job as of June 2013. That number is down from 46.3 percent
>   in 2010, as well as the previous low of 45.8 percent in 2011. Last
>   year, 47 percent of young adults were employed full-time.
>
> ([source: July 29, 2013](https://www.usnews.com/news/newsgram/articles/2013/07/29/full-time-employment-for-young-americans-is-decreasing))

Comment: The recent change to the title makes this question time-dependent. I think it should be changed back.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Been watching the question since 2012, and have no reason to believe that the title change impacts the validity of the question, now, or in the near future. If for some reason someone posted an answer, and the question became dated, it would be clear enough via the dates on the answer(s), question, and any references cited. Happy to change it back, but made the change to improve the question.

Comment: Of course some of those who graduated in the past 5 years are still in graduate school.

Comment: Also consider that a significant portion of graduates have married and are being a "homemaker" rather than working in a paid job.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Economic Policy Institute](https://www.epi.org)'s analysis of [unemployment and underemployment in recent college graduates](https://www.epi.org/chart/class-of-2019-coll-figure-e-the-underemployment-rate-for-young-college-grads-is-still-significantly-higher-than-it-was-before-the-recession-unemployment-and-underemployment-for-young-college-grad/?view=embed&embed_template=charts_v2013_08_21&embed_date=20190915&onp=167037&utm_source=epi_press&utm_medium=chart_embed&utm_campaign=charts_v2), we can see historical annual data for young college graduates aged 20-24 who are not enrolled in further schooling.

[image: Chart]

In June 2012 (the middle of the year), the average young graduate had

- An unemployment rate of 7.9%
- An underemployment rate of 16.1%, including all *involuntary* part-time workers, i.e. those who want full-time work but cannot find it
- An **employment rate** of (100 - 7.9 - 16.1) = **76%**

An overall employment rate of 76% makes the original claim **unlikely**. However, it's still **plausible** that the 26% gap is explained by *voluntary* part-time workers, who don't desire a full-time job. It's also possible that differences in the eligibility criteria contribute to the gap, since the students who graduated from 2006-2011 aren't the same as the recent college graduates aged 20-24.

Comment: How many went on to get another degree, though?  They would be neither employed nor unemployed.

Comment: You're correct in pointing out that the study I cited doesn't include people enrolled in further education, while OP's question doesn't specify a restriction like that.

Comment: The way the question is worded those going for another degree would be part of the half that weren't employed full time.